# opencv python script run in nodejs child_process: how I can interpret this error?

Tags: python, node.js, opencv, child-process

I have a python script using OpenCV. It works very well if i run i stand alone, but it gives me an unexpected error if I run it beside Node.js child_process.spawn().

This are the firsts lines of the script:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import argparse
import json
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Analyze a picture of the connector to check the ratio ....')
parser.add_argument('--filename', dest='filename', help='the filename of the picture to be analyzed', required=True)
parser.add_argument('--method', dest='method', help='the method used in the analysis: \'R\' for ROOT histo-fit method, \'M\' for a simple mathematical calculus', choices=['M', 'R'], default='M')

args = parser.parse_args()
print args
print "-------------------"

source_img = cv2.imread(args.filename)

gray_img=cv2.cvtColor(source_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

And this the code inside Node.JS:

```
script_path=__dirname+'/../../scripts/connector_check.py';
var pic_analysis = spawn ('python', [script_path, '--filename' , req.body.filename]);

pic_analysis.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
    });
```

When I run it,on the console I read:

```
stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):

stderr:   File "/home/osboxes/NSW-PCB-QC/app/oracle_calls/../../scripts/connector_check.py", line 21, in <module>

stderr:     
stderr: gray_img=cv2.cvtColor(source_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

stderr: cv2
stderr: .
stderr: error
stderr: : 
stderr: /home/osboxes/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.13/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3739: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor

stderr: 

child process exited with code 1
```

Of course, I tried with the same file.

Can someone help me to understand where I wrong?

Thank you guys

Comment: I'd make sure the image is being loaded correctly when launching from Node. I don't know Node, but it might be changing your working directory, resulting in the image file not being loaded.

Comment: I should have try this simple check. You're right, @Aurelius ! But in my partial defense, I have to say this error is a bit misleading. However, thank you!